# Query Postgres view using ent in golang

Tags: postgresql, go, view, ent

Given:

- ent table schema defined in golang, resulting in below table:

`create table scans ( id bigint generated by default as identity primary key, app_id bigint not null }`

- view of the table in plain sql I ran against postgres.

```
SELECT scans.id,
       scan.app_id,    
       row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY scans.app_id ORDER BY scans.id) AS scan_id
FROM main.scans;
```

How to query the view using ent? I'm not sure it's possible according to [this](https://github.com/ent/ent/issues/437) github issue.

Is querying the view using external go postgres library the only way?

Comment: a view is like a table and would be queried like a table